# Where can I put my .aws/credential file using cloudwatch api?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

Anyone helps me how to pass AWS key, secret key and token in CloudWatch function ?
I have also tried to pass all the credential array in CloudWatch but its still give me error to pass .aws/credential file, so I also put in my users folder than it give me error permission denied.

Here is function which I am using to implementing the CloudWatch PHP SDK of AWS

```
$cloudWatchClient = new CloudWatchClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => REGION,
]);
```

I also tried this but it's not working

```
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,TOKEN);


$cloudWatchClient = new CloudWatchClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => REGION,
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);
```

let me know how can I handle this ? or where can I put this file ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a bit more of context? running this locally or trying to run it on an AWS instance or you meant a Lambda Function?

The first code you put will only work on an AWS instance that has a role attached with those permissions.

The second code I imagine you have this ENVS declared somewhere else right ?

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
TOKEN
```

If you are not using `TOKEN` you should remove it too.

Comment: Currently, I'm running on my local server that I'll deploy on ec2 instance, and without token I don't have permission of access SDK functions.

I'm using PHP AWS SDK not lambda functions

Comment: ok in that case try to do this ```
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);


$cloudWatchClient = new CloudWatchClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => REGION,
    'credentials' => $credentials
]); ```

And replace AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY with your keys. Make sure the user for those keys has pemissions to do Cloudwatch operations

Comment: later when you deploy to AWS EC2 instance you dont need to put the credentials line, just assign a role to de EC2 instance with those permissions

Comment: I already tried but this is not working for me in cloudwatch function but when I used `$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY); ` this in s3 bucket its work for me but in cloudwatch is not working

Comment: your AWS user associated with those keys has permissions to do cloudwatch operations ? can you share the policy of that user?

Comment: Oh! one more thing, if you pass the credentials, you don't need to put this `'profile' => 'default',`

Comment: From where can I see my permission in AWS ?

Comment: probably the easiest way is to login to AWS console `http://console.aws.amazon.com` go to `IAM` service and search for your user, inside there you can see policies associated